# Cypress Page Object Model Issue:Got an error message when I ran a test linked to PageObject

Tags: javascript, automation, frameworks, cypress, pageobjects

Issue:
I got an error message in cypress when I ran the below code.
Error Message "_HomePage.default.getNameBox is not a function"

Code:
[image]

[image]

```
[![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

Comment: [**Please do not upload images of text (code/input/output/errors, or otherwise) on Stack Overflow**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question). You need to post a [mre] within the question itself, with [correct formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have some problems with capital letters in the variable names.

Instead of this

```
const Homepage = new HomePage();    // Homepage is the instance
HomePage.getNameBox()               // uses the class not the instance
```

the convention is to use a small char at the start of the instance

```
const homePage = new HomePage();
homePage.getNameBox()               // uses the instance
```